# Regex Matching for string pattern

Tags: regex

I have a data which is in the following form

```
5yrs 4mon
```

The mon part can vary from 1-12. I need help in writing a regex to extract the numeric value for mon. 
If for example the input is `5yrs 4mon` I would like a regex which returns 4.

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried already.

Comment: Please do some research. This is a question for google, not for StackOverflow.

Comment: clarified the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you're looking for is quite simple:

`\d+yrs\s(\d+)mon`

Explanation:

`\d+` - one or more digits

`\s\` - one space character

`(\d+)` - one or more digits, it's a capturing group that will have the value you're looking for.

If you need to validate the number and make sure it's exactly 1 to 12, there is a more advanced option:

`\d+yrs\s(1?[0-2]|\d)mon`

In this case, `13mon` will be invalid, for example.